# Mongo query $exists:false not behaving as expected

Tags: mongodb

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c541529fc3e371af7720346"), "name" : "Sanjeev", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : 122311223 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c541529fc3e371af7720347"), "name" : "siddhanth", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : "122311223", "age" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54158efc3e371af7720348"), "name" : "Sanjeev", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "skills" : [ "mountainclimbing" ], "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : 122311223 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54158efc3e371af7720349"), "name" : "siddhanth", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : "122311223", "age" : 30 }
```

The above is an example of my collection.

When I execute following query

```
> db.player.find({hobbies:{$elemMatch:{skills:{$exists:true}}}})
```

I get the following result where "hobbies" has "skills"

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54158efc3e371af7720348"), "name" : "Sanjeev", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "skills" : [ "mountainclimbing" ], "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : 122311223 }
```

But when I execute

```
> db.player.find({hobbies:{$elemMatch:{'skills':{$exists:false}}}})
```

I am getting records which has "skills" also.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c541529fc3e371af7720346"), "name" : "Sanjeev", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : 122311223 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c541529fc3e371af7720347"), "name" : "siddhanth", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : "122311223", "age" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54158efc3e371af7720348"), "name" : "Sanjeev", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "skills" : [ "mountainclimbing" ], "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : 122311223 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c54158efc3e371af7720349"), "name" : "siddhanth", "hobbies" : [ { "title" : "Trekking", "frequency" : 3 }, { "title" : "Cooking", "frequency" : 4 } ], "phone" : "122311223", "age" : 30 }
```

I am new to mongodb . What I am missing here ? Could you please explain.

Comment: Did you try db.player.find({ "hobbies.skills": { $exists: true }}).

Comment: Its working thanks ! Could you please explain why my query didnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.player.find({ hobbies:{ $elemMatch:{ skills:{ $exists:true }}}})
```

`$elemMatch` goes through each element inside the array and check for the condition if any of the array element matches the condition it returns the document.

```
db.player.find({ "hobbies.skills": { $exists: true }})
```

Whereas, the `.dot` notation verifies if each element inside the array satisfies the condition then only it returns the document.